# Select2 bootstrap styling issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have below issues for my select2 box.

1) I want to change the background-color to white of previously selected item. For eg when you open the select box and then hover on the next item the previous selected item has a background-color grey, which i want to change to white.

2) After an item is selected from the dropdown there are two borders displayed, want to get rid of one border in grey color.

```
Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/w50c4uqf/
```

[image: Issue1][image: Issue2]

Comment: we're here to help, but you're going to have to show some effort... show us what you've tried

Comment: Could you please tell why a down vote for the question ? i tried to change various css classes and couldn't do it and thus i posted on stackoverflow.

Comment: you haven't included code, the things you tried... etc... a simple fiddler link is not allowed for good reason...

Comment: Could you please check my solution @koolhuman?

Comment: i resolved the first issue by overriding below classes .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background-color: #fff!important; }
  
 .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background-color: #5897fb!important;
  color: white; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CSS code which changes the color of previous selected item:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background-color: #ddd; //Change this color 
}
```

You can go inside *select2.css* file and change this directly like:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
      background-color: #fff;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/w50c4uqf/5/

For removing the border you should add this line:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single:focus {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks !! but by using your code and making the color to white the previous selected item disappears.

Comment: I solved it as well. Could you please check again the last update.

Comment: now the blue highlighted color is not appearing on the previous selected item :-|

Comment: Finally, I solved it correctly. Using !important is usually dangerous that's why I changed the line directly by going inside select2.css file and it works for now.

Comment: could you please tell me where all you changed in select2.css ? i can override those classes. Because i don't want to change anything in select2.css file

Comment: Only line I changed is .select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
      background-color: #fff;
} in select2.css file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107076/discussion-between-kaan-burak-sener-and-koolhuman).

Comment: i resolved the first issue by overriding below classes .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background-color: #fff!important; }
  
 .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background-color: #5897fb!important;
  color: white; }